# The base class includes the field '', but its type () is not compatible with the type of control ()

Tags: c#, user-controls

I'm working on an application that builds fine locally, but blows up with the following error when we deploy:

> The base class includes the field 'followUs', but its type (FollowUs) is not >compatible with the type of control (ASP.includes_ctrls_png_followus_ascx).

I feel like I've tried every suggestion I can find on the development side.  What's weird is that I renamed the user control to just "FollowUs" and re-deployed but I'm still getting the error referring to the old namespace "includes_ctrls_png_followus_ascx".  We're using Visual Studio's Release Management tool to deploy but I'm pretty green with it.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

Had to move the control to the same folder as the control that wrapped it.  Didn't want to but it worked.  This seems to be the standard answer, just can't figure out why it runs fine locally but blows up on our dev server.  Works though, hope this helps someone.